How to shorten datetime class string that seems to go into the microseconds
Here is the problem.  I am getting data from an API GET call that contains some data from a remote database that appears to be a datetime type.  But the deal is that the string is too long.  It is so long that a SharePoint List will not accept it as a DateTime type.
Here is an example of this faulty data:
 "2021-06-01T14:46:41.5866667Z"

It seems to me that this data represents seconds and fractions of seconds.  Please tell me what sort of API calls from a DateTime class or some other rational process I can use to convert this data into a more usable format like this:
"2021-06-01T14:46:52.42Z"


"But the deal is that the string is too long." This sentence and then "a more usable format" seem to imply that you think it's fundamentally a bad idea to have precise data. I'd say it's the other way round - if SharePoint won't accept data with (say) microsecond precision, that's a problem with SharePoint. (And I'd also say that a date/time format showing hundredths of seconds instead of milliseconds is a bit confusing.) But fundamentally your question is unclear - are you actually looking for how to format a DateTime, or how to truncate the data in a DateTime?

It would also help if you'd clarify what level of precision SharePoint can accept.

Do you pass the value as string or as actual DateTime to Share Point? Because this seems to be a totally fine ISO Date Time and should be parseable in C#.

@Jon Skeet, I am looking for a way to truncate the date in the DateTIme.  There seems to be functional issues with having the longer version in my first example that arises in the C# code.

In that case, you could just use new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond) or similar. But note how your question has received an answer which is all about string formatting, which shows you should edit your question to be clearer.

The string you are dealing with is in ISO 8601 format, where the long fraction represents the number of seconds down to fractions of a second. To make this more SharePoint-compatible (which expects a simpler datetime format), you can truncate the fractional seconds to two decimal places or remove them entirely if not needed.
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string originalDateTime = "2021-06-01T14:46:41.5866667Z";
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(originalDateTime);

        // Format to two decimal places
        string formattedDateTime = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffZ");

        Console.WriteLine(formattedDateTime);
    }
}

